# How initialize binding in android test class?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, testing, android-espresso

How initialize binding in test class?  , I'm trying to write UI tests using espresso and I want to fetch views by binding.

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class AuthFragmentTest{

```
private lateinit var scenario: FragmentScenario<AuthFragment>
private lateinit var binding: FragmentAuthBinding
private lateinit var usernameEditText: TextInputEditText
private lateinit var passwordEditText: TextInputEditText
private lateinit var submitButton: MaterialButton

@Before
fun setup(){
    scenario = launchFragmentInContainer(themeResId = R.style.Theme_Main)
    scenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
    binding
    usernameEditText = binding.usernameInputEditText
    passwordEditText = binding.passwordInputEditText
    submitButton = binding.uSubmit
}

@Test
fun testUserInput(){
    usernameEditText.setText("user")
    passwordEditText.setText("pass")
    Espresso.closeSoftKeyboard()
    val a = submitButton.isVisible
    Thread.sleep(10000)
    assertThat(a).isTrue()
}
```

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70364122/error-inflating-viewbinding-in-test-class-binary-xml-file-line-38-binary-xml/70364919#70364919), it may be useful. You need to pass an inflater to the binding method to set it's views.

Comment: You can type the text in EditText in testcases using by doing this,

      `Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(<<Id of your edittext>>)).perform(ViewActions.scrollTo()).perform(ViewActions.typeText("Text you want to type"));`